# SVN as Maven Repo

Tags: svn, maven-2, maven

We are using SVN to store maven dependencies (organization restriction couldn't use nexus or artifactory maven repository as now). SVN runs on a webserver with https protocol. Currently if a new dependency is added all developers have to update their local copy of maven repo manually. Is there a way to download\update new dependency automatically during maven build cycle itself? tried with wagon plugin no help. Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First try to get a Nexus as soon as possible. Furthermore you are using svn as a replacement for the local user repository. Why not using SVN as a (temporary) replacement for a nexus which users are using via Maven. If you configure the Web-Server that way everyone will download the dependencies automatically via Maven and NOT via SVN into the .m2/repository.

Comment: How should i configure web-server to download dependencies automatically?

Comment: Are you accessing SVN via http protocol? If so just configure the repository access to that (settings.xml)...

Comment: we use https url to access svn

Comment: Ok fine than you can configure Maven to use this as a Maven repository (should be working)...But i recommend as soon as possible to change to a Nexus like solution, cause it much simpler and has more options etc.

Comment: how to configure maven with svn repo be elaborate in your answers

Answer (score 1):

You can make a shared folder accessible to all developers and configure maven to use it as repository and create a script to update it on a build. So every body will have the same updated repo.

But its better for you to force getting nexus...

Comment: We have already checked in dependency to SVN. need a solution using svn only

Answer (score 0):

I understand your situation as we were in a similar situation. What you need to use is a local Maven repository Manager - we use [Apache Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org) on a local build machine (its actually an old laptop on our LAN). I'm sure there are other alternatives to using Archiva, but it's the only one with which I have experience.

Once installed, you will probably need to have everyone add this repository to their ~/.m2.settings.xml file, and mark it as a mirror for everything (this means that each users Maven build will head to the Archiva repo for all of its dependencies (at least, those not stored within the local repo on the users machine). If Archiva does not contain the dependency, it can be configured to download it itself, and store within the Archiva repo for other users.

(let me know if you'd like more details, and i'll update this post with more info, including pom snippets, etc, that you'll need to use)

HTH

Comment: Archiva is alike nexus or artifactory. We need to stick to svn as now